# Migrate into custom File Type

Tags: files, migrations

I am writing the script for a file migration and am using the `MigrateDestinationFile` method.  I noticed that when I migrate the files that they default to the `Document` file type.  However, I have created custom file types and want the files to be migrated to those file types.

How can I do so?

I was hoping I could do something like this, but it's not working:

```
$this->destination = new MigrateDestinationFile('custom_file_type');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really wish this was better documented.  In addition to the above you need to add a field mapping to the type:

```
$this->destination = new MigrateDestinationFile('custom_file_type');    
$this->addFieldMapping('type')->defaultValue('custom_file_type');
```

That's it!